# How do I find the smallest positive integer that can be written as a linear combination of 2191 and 1351?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

This is one of my assigned questions, but I don't understand how to answer it as there was nothing like it in any of the example questions. I'm able to write the $gcd(2191, 1351)$ as a linear combination in the form $7 = 37(2191) - 60(1351)$ but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: You are done, every integer that can be written in form $2191x+1351y$ is divisible by 7.

Comment: Your $7$ answers the question, since every linear combination (with integer coefficients) of these two numbers is a multiple of $7.$

Comment: Knowing that $7$ is a linear combination of $2191$ and $1351$, all you still need to check is whether any of $1,2,3,4,5,6$ is also such a linear combination. (They aren't, but can you see why?)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Hmm, unfortunately, I can't see why...

Comment: The other two comments explained the reason.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the smallest positive integer that can be written as an integer linear combination of $a$ and $b$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. This is a consequence of [Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). Since you have determined that $\gcd(2191,1351)=7$, you have already answered your question.